# Set local storage in Cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

For one of our applications, I need to set local storage in order to bypass the login page process.

I have the following function that will return the accessToken that I need to set. This function works when running in node.

```
async function getAccessToken(email, pwd) {
    const form = {email: email, password: pwd};
    let config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        }
    };
    const accessToken = await axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/loginWithToken`, qs.stringify(form), config);
    console.log(accessToken.data.accessToken);
    return accessToken.data.accessToken
}
```

I'm trying to create a cypress command that will set local storage, then visit the application. When running, I get an error that I returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("logInAs", async(Useremail, Userpwd, TMURL) => {
    var accessToken = cy.task('getAccessToken', {email: Useremail, pwd: Userpwd
    }).then(Visit =>{
        window.localStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
        window.localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", accessToken);
        cy.visit(`${process.env.TM_API_URL}/`+TMURL+``);
    });
});
```

I've also tried the following cypress command

```
require('dotenv').config();

Cypress.Commands.add('logInAs3', (Useremail, Userpwd, TMURL) => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `${process.env.API_URL}/loginWithToken`,
            body: {
                user: {
                    email: Useremail,
                    password: Userpwd,
                }
            }
        })
            .then((resp) => {
                window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', resp.body.data.data.accessToken);
                window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', resp.body.data.data.accessToken);
                cy.visit(`${process.env.TM_API_URL}/`+TMURL+``, {failOnStatusCode: false})
            })
    });
```

But I get the following error. The URL I need to post to in order to get the access token, is a different domain than the base url. So using the base in the post will not work for me.

> cy.request() must be provided a fully qualified url - one that begins
>   with 'http'. By default cy.request() will use either the current
>   window's origin or the 'baseUrl' in cypress.json. Neither of those
>   values were present.

Comment: Please elaborate on `I need to set local storage in order to bypass the login page process`. Do you also control the backend that sets this token? Is that only done in your integration tests?

Comment: We have a test API that will generate these tokens, so yes, we control it. This app shares some functionality with another app which doesn't allow the typical cypress username/password bypass option to work. I need to grab the token from the response, set the local storage, then navigate to my desired page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one:

In `cypress.json`

```
{
  "env": {
    "EXTERNAL_API": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
  }
}
```

In `support/commands.js`

```
Cypress.Commands.add('logInAs3', (Useremail, Userpwd, TMURL) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${Cypress.env('EXTERNAL_API')}/loginWithToken`,
    body: {
      user: {
        email: Useremail,
        password: Userpwd,
      }
    }
  })
    .its('body')
    .then((body) => {
      window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', body.data.data.accessToken);
      window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', body.data.data.accessToken);
    })
});
```

Inside your test

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.logInAs3()
})

it('check localStorage token', () => {
  cy.visit()
  expect(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')).not.null
  expect(localStorage.getItem('refreshToken')).not.null
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on the @Danny answer, you can use the [cypress-localstorage-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands) package to persist localStorage and reuse same user session for all tests in a block:

In `cypress.json`

```
{
  "env": {
    "EXTERNAL_API": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"
  }
}
```

In `support/commands.js`

```js
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";

Cypress.Commands.add('logInAs', (UserEmail, UserPwd) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${Cypress.env('EXTERNAL_API')}/loginWithToken`,
    body: {
      user: {
        email: UserEmail,
        password: UserPwd,
      }
    }
  })
    .its('body')
    .then((body) => {
      cy.setLocalStorage("accessToken", body.data.accessToken);
      cy.setLocalStorage("refreshToken", body.data.refreshToken);
    });
});
```

Inside your tests:

```js
describe("when user FOO is logged in", ()=> {
  before(() => {
    cy.logInAs("foo@foo.com", "fooPassword");
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();
    cy.visit("");
  });

  it('should exist accessToken in localStorage', () => {
    cy.getLocalStorage("accessToken").should("exist");
  });

  it('should exist refreshToken in localStorage', () => {
    cy.getLocalStorage("refreshToken").should("exist");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hitting login API every time a Test Run's cost resources at both(Server and Client)

here is optimized way:

> Just store login/auth API Success response in Cypress Env and  reuse
> it in command function

In `cypress.json`

```
{
  "myenv": {
    "authResponse": {
      "apiToken": "jwt_token_received_from_server",
      "refreshToken": "refresh_token_received_from_server"
    }
  }
}
```

In `support/commands.js`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('setSession', () => {
  const accessToken = `${Cypress.env('myenv')['authResponse']['apiToken']}`
  const refreshToken = `${Cypress.env('myenv')['authResponse']['refreshToken']}`
  window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
  window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', responseToken);
  })
});
```

Inside your test

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.setSession();
})

it('Test Ui Components for Authorized User', () => {

})
```

Comment: The localstorage values no longer exists after `cy.visit` or `cy.navigateTo` though....