# Storing access token in Cypress - Cypress OAuth 2.0

Tags: typescript, oauth-2.0, cypress

For my application I'm trying to login via the API and not the UI

I'm required to store the accessToken to navigate through the application

My current login method looks like this

```
 Cypress.Commands.add('login', (overrides = {}) => {
  Cypress.log({
    name: 'loginViaAuth0',
  });

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: Cypress.env('auth_url'),
      headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
      username: Cypress.env('auth_username'),
      password: Cypress.env('auth_password'),
    }
  }

  cy.request(options);
});
```

I need to store the accessToken to the resource file. I have tried various methods like on here but without success

[Set local storage in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431316/set-local-storage-in-cypress)

Thank you

Edit:

I have tried this but still no luck

```
 Cypress.Commands.add('login', (overrides = {}) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: Cypress.env('auth_url'),
    body: {
      user: {
        email: Cypress.env('auth_username'),
        password: Cypress.env('auth_password'),
      }
    }
  })
    .its('token')
    .then((token) => {
      window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token);
    });
});
```

Edit: this worked in the end for anybody interested

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (overrides = {}) => {
cy.request({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: Cypress.env('auth_url'), form: true, 
    body: { grant_type: 'client_credentials', scope: 'xero_all-apis' ,
           username: Cypress.env('auth_username'), 
           password: Cypress.env('auth_password'), } }) 
    .its('body') 
   .then(res => { 
     cy.setLocalStorage('accessToken',res.accessToken);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Hi. You just have to read the request response and save the token to `sessionsStorage`. BTW, I think is not the best way (in this case) to declare the payload as a `const`, then assign it to `cy.request`. Just set it directly to request body `cy.request({ ... }).its('body.token').then(token => { window.sessionsStorage.setItem('accessToken', token) })`

Comment: Cypress.Commands.add('login', (overrides = {}) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: Cypress.env('auth_url'),
    body: {
      user: {
        email: Cypress.env('auth_username'),
        password: Cypress.env('auth_password'),
      }
    }
  })
    .its('body.token')
    .then((token) => {
      window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token);
    });
});



like so? I'm getting

Comment: Timed out retrying: cy.its() errored because the property: token does not exist on your subject.

cy.its() waited for the specified property token to exist, but it never did.

If you do not expect the property token to exist, then add an assertion such as:

cy.wrap({ foo: 'bar' }).its('quux').should('not.exist')

Comment: hey, it doesn't have to be `body.token`, it could be `body.access_token`. You have to find out from the response the right path/structure. Also, I do recommend storing your token in the `sessionStorage`, so you have it cleared when the session is done.

Comment: My answer match with this answer. So, please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59016663/14910874

Comment: @ArekKhatry  Thank you, i have the accesstoken now in local storage but my last problem is that it is now 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

@Steven983, Please try this

```
Cypress code Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => { 
cy.request({ 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: Cypress.env('auth_url'), form: true, 
    body: { grant_type: 'client_credentials', scope: 'xero_all-apis' }, 
    auth: { 
           username: Cypress.env('auth_username'), 
           password: Cypress.env('auth_password'), } }) 
    .its('body') 
   .then(res => { 
     cy.log(res.body.accessToken) //To verify token is shown in console
     cy.setLocalStorage('accessToken', res.body.accessToken); 
   });
```

});

Comment: it is returning the token but it is showing as undefined https://imgur.com/a/Zn866jG

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share the cypress code and the API response (can use postman) to understand json schema.  Also,  .its('body')
  .then(identity => {
    cy.log(identity.token) // Does this print the token in console ??
 
  });

Comment: API Response {
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Im5hdGhhbi5oZXdpdHRAZWN1dGVzdGluZy5jb20iLCJyZWFsbSI6InVzZXIiLCJuYW1laWQiOiItMSIsIm5iZiI6MTYwOTk0NzgzNSwiZXhwIjoxNjEwMDM0MjM1LCJpYXQiOjE2MDk5NDc4MzV9.mtnnMYlV47rgvVyEhkfmKSE_eZFnjgIr-PXgvRJKTY4",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "isValid": true,
    "UserId": 1
}

Comment: Cypress code  Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: Cypress.env('auth_url'),
    form: true, // sets to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    body: {
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      scope: 'xero_all-apis'
    },
    auth: {
      username: Cypress.env('auth_username'),
     password: Cypress.env('auth_password'),
    }
  })
  .its('body')
  .then(res => {
    cy.setLocalStorage('accessToken', res.token);
  });
});

Comment: @Steven983, I have edited my answer. Please look at that, it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far, appreciate it.. and do not blame you if you stop there ;)  i have tried your edited answer and this happened. https://imgur.com/a/Zm0xxJ1

Comment: Sad to hear that it didn't work. I will be happy if I can help you in any other way. I had written this blog related to API testing which might be helpful but not sure for this problem . https://ramesh-khatri.medium.com/api-automation-using-cypress-bc721e98ced5

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your help. i imagine the problem is related to the app and not the method of testing

Comment: I got it to work, i just had to include the username and pass in the body

Comment: Okay. That's Great.